# How to find out that at which position Rx filters condition is satisfied and return that array index number

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

### how to make this kind function ? is there should be flatMap or any other aggregate ? is there any other way to do this by Rxandroid ?

```
 # raw Data #
====================

 private List<DataBean> list=new ArrayList<>();

 list.add(new DataBean(1))
 list.add(new DataBean(8))
 list.add(new DataBean(3))
 list.add(new DataBean(8))
 list.add(new DataBean(9))
```

---

```
Observable.from(list).filter(new Func<DataBean, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(DataBean Data) {
            Data.getId()==8;

          return <-- position should be Array index
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer pos) {

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with some stateful (and a bit convoluted) set of operators:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.range(1, 10)
    .compose(indexOf(v -> v == 5))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Observable.range(1, 10)
    .compose(indexOf(v -> v == 12))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, Integer> indexOf(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    return o -> Observable.defer(() -> {
        int[] index = { -1, -1 };
        return o.filter(v -> {
            index[0]++;
            if (predicate.test(v)) {
                index[1] = index[0];
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
        .takeWhile(v -> index[1] != -1)
        .ignoreElements()
        .andThen(Observable.fromCallable(() -> index[1]));
    });
}
```